# Could we more strongly discourage users from deleting their own questions (non-duplicates with no downvotes)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions

I've seen it a number of times that new users post questions which are perhaps not *great*, but definitely *worthwhile*, yet after a comment (either pointing out something that's not clear enough to give a precise answer, a thought-mistake that makes the problem somewhat trivial, or giving some literature reference that indirectly answers the question), their reaction is to *completely delete the question*.

Now, I can understand the reaction of wanting to remove “shameful” content (“silly me, I should have read the doc introduction better...”), but actually I think some of these questions would be particularly useful for future users stumbling into the same rookie issue.

What would be a good message to add to the “sure you want to delete?” that would urge the OP to consider the possibility that the content might still be useful, and encouraging to instead edit the question to become actually *good*, even if the OP themselves doesn't really need it anymore?

(I don't propose making it *impossible* to delete a question before it has upvoted answers, just making users aware that it may not be a nice thing to do.)

Comment: I had a similar experience with this on a duplicate question; the user asked a question, and I knew I had seen something similar before; I found the duplicate, but it was asked in a completely different way, and I could understand how the user couldn't find the dup with their way of looking at the issue. After flagging the dup, I added a note : "You'll find your answer in this question, but please don't delete your question, that way someone with your same issue can find their solution." Obviously you're talking about non-dups, but it's the same idea, they're ashamed it exists and delete.

Comment: Keep in mind that at this point, the same question has most often been asked before. Particularly true for rookie questions. So the vast majority of such questions could be deleted with no harm done.

Comment: The really annoying thing is when the poster does this 2 or 3 times.

Comment: @Lundin not sure if I understood you right there... if you're saying “most rookie-level questions that could possibly ever be asked, have already been asked on SO by now” then I beg to differ: there will always be countless unasked questions on any level. Duplicates do of course happen often enough, but they're not the subject here, as I emphasized right in the title. (When I see a duplicate, I tend to mjölnir it out of sight, rather than commenting or starting to write an answer...)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, most of them have indeed been asked before. In case of older/established technologies, most beginner questions had already been asked _before SO was even launched_ as a site. The chance of a beginner coming up with something new to ask is very rare. My point is that there's going to be too few such questions worth preserving, to motivate site changes and new features.

Comment: @Lundin well ok, in a language like C you're probably right, because it comes with so few abstractions and is so extensively covered already. But most languages have much more built in that gives a hard-to-exhaust scope of questions before you even scrape the surface much. This is certainly the case for Haskell (which admittedly is an extreme in the other direction).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Nah, beginners will not (and should not) dig into peripheral libraries and special features. Take for example something like multi-threading: beginners can't even ask about that, because it is a rather advanced topic, and sensible questions about it will per definition not be beginner questions. And even if you are a beginner to multi-threading, there will be the FAQs on that subject too.

Comment: It seems like you're basically debating the definition of who should be called “a beginner”. (Again I'd say this depends a lot on the programming language – to name Haskell once more, parallelisation is so simple that it might well be classified as a beginner topic; OTOH, some stuff concerning IO interaction which is very basic in procedural languages readily throws you into a category-theory quagmire). But this is not really relevant here; the point is these questions _get asked_ (by whomever) and deleted again, and I think this isn't good.

Comment: And even if the issue is specific to “exotic” technologies: each of these may be much smaller than C, Java or Python, but _collectively_ they make up a sizable part of StackOverflow.

Comment: As I recall, there are blood-curdling warnings attached to every other action that may contribute to a question ban, I don't see why deleting one's own questions should be left out.

Comment: I can’t access it yet but… cannot hi-rep users [vote for undeleting](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17159/what-is-the-purpose-of-allowing-undelete-votes-on-a-question-the-op-deleted) an _exceptionally good_ rookie question?

Comment: We can **prevent self-deletion** of a recently-asked question or one with a recent (not-yet-upvoted) answer, but I'm not sure whether this will be better or worse for the site (in that there are probably more people deleting their bad questions in this period than those who are deleting a truly useful question).

Comment: I totally disagree with the Stack Exchange mantra, 'the question cannot be deleted because it may be helpful'. The user can add content and therefore should have the same right of removal. This is especially true if they have managed to post duplicate, yet easily answered and therefore up voted content.

Comment: Is there any evidence to suggest our current self-deletion disclaimer ("We do not recommend deleting questions with answers...") has any effect?

Comment: @williamdnapier When you post content on Stack Exchange, you grant SE a particular license.  You may not revoke that license.  You are allowed to add content; you are explicitly and by-design must give up full ownership (including the right of deletion) by doing so.  You may not take your ball and go home.  If this displeases you, do not post content on SE websites.  The damage done by deleting content is worse than the benefit gained by the content being added in the first place.

Comment: @Yakk Obviously, I agreed to the license terms of Stack Exchange in order to use the site. I do, however, disagree with this area of those terms from a philosophical standpoint. This is not a zero sum point of view.

Comment: @williamdnapier could you elaborate what you mean by “not a zero sum point of view”?

Comment: @will no large collaberative venture can survive if any contributor can retroactively remove all past contributions.  Your position basically is a practical one saying collaberation should not work.  I get it; I want a pony too.  Doesn't make it happen.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, I know. Just an opinion, that's all.

Comment: @Yakk There are plenty of sites that allow user contributions that have no  problem allowing a user to remove all of their contributions at any time.  It's a problem for SO because SO is trying to create a repository of knowledge that's useful long term.  *Lots* of sites based entirely around user contributions aren't trying to do that, and have no problem allowing a user to take their ball and go home with it.  Look at Facebook, Twitter,  YouTube, etc.  In all of these cases a user can delete all of their content at any time.  SO is actually unusual (though not unique) in this regard.

Comment: @Servy Facebook, Twitter and YouTube aren't really _collaborative ventures_ – removing your content there is not so much taking your ball and leaving, as taking your shirt and leaving.

Comment: @leftaroundabout How are Facebook and Twitter not collaborative?  YouTube is maybe a *bit* more of a stretch (although I don't think much).  Again, all of these sites are built *entirely* around users consuming and interacting with other uses' contributed content.  If you don't consider these "collaborative", then I don't understand what you mean by "collaborative" in this context. What type of collaboration does SO have that those sites don't that makes SO special?

Comment: @Servy well ok, it's hard to argue they're not collaborative, it's rather that they're not _ventures_, in the sense that most of the collaboration happens in the moment. As you say, the difference is that StackOverflow is emphasized the _long-term_.

Answer (score 19):

We already have a mechanism to motivate users to keep their *stupid* question. It is - reputation. Simply upvote the question **you find useful** and they will not delete it.

If your answer is useful, it will get upvoted as well and the user will be [unable to delete the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/299295).

Comment: Upvotes alone don't prevent users from deleting their question. And I'm generally reluctant to upvote a question that is still in need of some editing; it's not like these questions are _perfect as they are_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If they are not up-vote worthy, they can hardly be worthy of preservation.

Comment: @yivi There are plenty of SO posts I wouldn't _upvote_, yet consider preservation-worthy. Some questions are just plain boring, trivial to answer, phrased without much effort... I don't see what to reward these people for, yet it's good their posts are in the system because somebody in the future might have the same problem, and they then _don't_ have to ask at all.

Comment: If the question is bad enough as to not merit an up-vote, the only thing that could make it preservation worthy is the rare good/useful answer to a bad question. And in that case, upvoting the answer is enough to protect the question from self-deletion. If neither q nor deserve a single upvote, nothing of value is lost when deleted, IMO.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If a question is trivially answered, then it's *not* valuable to keep it around for future people, as those future people could trivially answer it.

Comment: @Servy in an ideal world, yes, but actually what happens then is that those future people don't bother thinking anymore than the first one, and _ask a new question_, wasting everybody's time yet again. If the first post of the trivial question is kept around, they will at least with some likelyhood find it. — Anyway, this proposal isn't actually about trivial questions, that was just an example illustrating that there's no dichotomy between _good questions_ and _deletion-worthy questions_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The people that ask those types of questions are going to do that even if you *don't* delete the question.  Keeping around even more copies of answers to easily found solutions doesn't help people who aren't actually doing their research before asking to find the solutions.

Comment: @Servy I trust even the laziest GimmeTehCodez people to try Google once, before asking StackOverflow. But again, these _laziest_ are not what I'm talking about here (one-line questions in general _are_ deletion-worthy), but the people that are too lazy to do some proper work themselves, but at least dedicated enough to coherently phrase out a question.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Considering how many questions I see people ask that are answered by copy-pasting their own question into google, I most certainly do not trust the laziest of the question askers to do even a single google search first.  I've seen too many thousands of examples of people not having done it to be able to still have that trust.

Comment: @Servy evidently I'm lucky to not participate in the `.net` tags, if it's that bad there. But, this still has no bearing to the discussion here. If a bad question is duped, not nice, but at least it enables the most efficient of remedial tools: the dupe hammer, faster than any self-deletion.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's not a reason to *prevent* those types of questions from being self-deleted.  It's still more work for the community to have people going around closing questions as duplicates than for the author to self-delete them and save them the effort, or to remove yet another bad duplicate question if it has already been closed (the more likely case).

Comment: @Servy I think I've said it a number of times now: **I do not care about those trivial questions**, like, really not care in the sense of, it doesn't matter to me what happens to them. If you insist on sticking to that subject, then I'd still say that those people are actually also not very likely to self-delete their questions, so the discussion here has little bearing on them. — What I do care about are questions which are _in principle quite good_, just have some significant flaw that requires editing before they can be properly answered, to which point it never gets because of deletion.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, I'm aware that you don't care about the bad questions that you're preventing from being deleted.  I'm saying that I, and plenty of others, *do care*.  While it's not an enormous percentage of people asking bad questions that self-delete them, it's still a sizable number, more than it sounds like you expect.  The *good* questions that you don't want to be deleted can be trivially prevented from deletion by upvotes, which if they really are good, you should be doing, and the authors wouldn't have reason to delete them (because they're good useful questions).

Comment: Why do you jump to _bad questions_ now? I said nothing about those. (Oh, actually I did, in the context of dupes, but that was itself off the topic...) Bad questions should be downvoted, and I explicitly narrowed my OP to questions without downvotes. Sure, peer-pressured self-deletion is more likely and by all means a good thing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm bringing up bad questions because *I care about bad questions not being prevented from being deleted*.  Again, I'm aware that you don't care at all about preventing bad questions from being deleted, you've said as much, and that's fine, I can't force you to care about them, but the change you're proposing will affect them, and so I care, and so I'm discussing them.  If someone realizes they've asked a bad question, we *want* them to be able to delete it, and we don't want to force the community to have to deal with it with downvotes/close votes first.

Comment: @Servy ok, you've misunderstood me there. I said I do not care about _trivial_ questions, provided they are not bad; trivial questions being questions that are coherent, answerable, but unlikely (yet not impossible!) to be of any future use, and can easily be ignored on the front page because it's evident how simple they are. — I do care about the deletion of _bad_ questions, i.e. questions that actually have negative value, thus I upfront excluded downvoted questions from the OP. And downvotes are, I'm afraid, also necessary to make those people to even consider self-deletion.

Comment: @leftaroundabout A question that isn't going to be useful to anyone is a bad question.  It might not be *as* bad as some other questions, but it's still a bad question.  And no, downvotes aren't necessary to get people to delete bad questions.  In my experiences a very large portion of people asking questions like these don't care at all about votes, they're just here to get their answer, not to get points.  They're more than happy to delete their 0 scored question when they've gotten what they want.  I find it rare to see people asking good questions and then trying to delete them.